# Extending network with 2 airport express from another router

Tags: airport

I have two airport express devices. Is it possible to extend my one airport express with another airport express.

Comment: Given the discussion under Martin's answer, you need to modify your question, it doesn't accurately reflect what you want to do, which is to extend a third, non-Apple router with the two AirPort Express units.

Comment: The "extend non-Apple" part will most likely give you problems.  Consider upgrading the central router.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, you have to configure your second airport express with the option to Extend Wireless Network.

This is how my network looks (names blurred just in case):

[image: Airports]

ANd this is the configuration for the Airport 2 (the one extending the network created by Airport 1:

[image: Config]

Comment: as I undestand your first airpot is connected with a cable. Can I do the same if both airports are connected wirelessly?

Comment: @sinan Yes, you should be able to do that.  But aren't you going to connect to the internet at some point?

Comment: Yes I have another wireless modem (which is not apple) I want to extend that wireless modem with 2 airport express. When it is set as "Join existing network" it works fine. But when I choose "extend" It says "updating" and then it's lost. I have to manually reset the device. Any ideas?

Comment: Then there must be some strange incompatibility. Can you try using one airport in place of that "other modem" only for testing? Try to create an apple wireless network and extend that one using your second airport. Yes, my 1st airport is connected with a cable.

Comment: @sinan Can you extend it successfully with 1 AirPort and it is failing on the second?  Or does it fail with both?